# Eliminar elemento de array bidimensional

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo

```
var array = [["ENERO","20/01/2020",18,2,20],
             ["ENERO","21/01/2020",17,1,22],
             ["ENERO","22/01/2020",16,2,26]]
```

Necesito eliminar en este caso todos los elementos que dicen "ENERO", pero puede cambiar "FEBRERO", "MARZO", Etc
Entiendo que para recorrer el array puedo usar.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          array.splice( i, 1 ); 
    }
```

Esto me elimina el array generado. No el primer elemento de cada fila.

Comment: ¿Agregarías por favor lo que llevas al momento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres eliminar el primer elemento usa

```
array.splice( x, 1 )
```

Donde x es la posición del elemento que quieres quitar

en tu caso `array.splice( 0, 1 )`

Si solo quieres eliminar el primer elemento del array interno

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { array[i].splice( 0, 1 ); }
```

Comment: asi array.splice( 0, 1 )

Comment: Me elimina todo el array creado, no solo los primeros elementos de todas las filas.

Comment: Si lo pones dentro del for si te va a eliminar todo, no logro entenderte muy bien que es lo que quieres :(, pones este array de ejemplo `var array = [["ENERO","20/01/2020",18,2,20],
             ["ENERO","21/01/2020",17,1,22],
             ["ENERO","22/01/2020",16,2,26]]` cual es la salida que esperas?

Comment: Esta salida var array = [["20/01/2020",18,2,20], ["21/01/2020",17,1,22], ["22/01/2020",16,2,26]]

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          array[i].splice( 0, 1 );       
   }`

Comment: Eso era! Genial jorge muchas gracias! modifica tu repuesta asi cierro la pregunta

Comment: De nada, ya modifique la respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de una estructura de este tipo

```
var array = [["ENERO","20/01/2020",18,2,20],
             ["ENERO","21/01/2020",17,1,22],
             ["ENERO","22/01/2020",16,2,26]]
```

Me valgo del método `flat` para transformar esa estructura de tipo matriz a un vector

```
let final = array.flat()
```

Como nos interesa obtener de vuelta todos los datos menos aquellos que digan **ENERO**" entonces usamos el bucle `filter` el cual nos retornará un nuevo vector dado por una regla establecida.

En este caso indicamos que por cada elemento que se itere no tome o considere un valor por medio de este operador !=

```
let final2 = final.filter((elemento) => elemento != "ENERO") 

console.log(final2)
```

Comment: Creo que se interpreto mal la pregunta, necesito eliminar todos los elementos primeros, es decir todos los "enero" no solo en el primero. En este caso dice enero pero puede decir otra cosa.

Comment: @MTDesigner remuevo mi respuesta entonces considera editar tu pregunta y ser un poco mas claro por favor

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que hay dos opciones, o borrar la palabra 'ENERO' o borrar el registro que contiene 'ENERO', manteniendo la estructura original aquí te dejo las dos opciones.

```js
var array = [["ENERO", "20/01/2020", 18, 2, 20],
["FEBRERO", "21/01/2020", 17, 1, 22],
["ENERO", "22/01/2020", 16, 2, 26]];


const opcion1 = array.map(e=>e.filter(m=>m!=='ENERO'));

console.log(opcion1);

console.log("----");

const opcion2 = array.filter(e=>!e.some(m=>m==='ENERO'));

console.log(opcion2);
```

En el primer caso, como se mantiene la cantidad de elementos del primer array, se puede usar `.map()` y `.filter()` para el segundo nivel, que no mantiene la misma cantidad de elementos. En la segunda opción se usa `.filter()` y la negacion de `.some()` (que no es lo mismo que `.every()`) para excluír los registros que contengan 'ENERO'.